# Splitness of quotient sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, vector-bundles, exact-sequence

Let $A, B, C$ be holomorphic vector bundles over some complex manifold $X$. Let $A', B', C'$ be sub bundles, respectively. Suppose that we have short exact sequences:

$$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$

$$0 \rightarrow A' \rightarrow B' \rightarrow C' \rightarrow 0$$

Let's also suppose that the quotient sequence

$$0 \rightarrow A / A' \rightarrow B / B' \rightarrow C / C' \rightarrow 0$$

is also exact. For example, the map between sub bundles $A' \rightarrow B'$ is induced from the map $A \rightarrow B$.

If the first sequence is in fact split, can one conclude that the quotient sequence is also split? If not, what further conditions does one need to impose for it to be split?

Comment: Also, $A'$ must be mapped into $B'$, and $B'$ into $C'$, for this to even be a sequence.

Comment: @user26857: Exactness follows from the snake lemma: the kernels are all zero.

Comment: @Hurkyl Good point.  I am not used to thinking about holomorphic bundles, but I guess the snake lemma applies to the larger (abelian) category of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules?

Comment: @user26857 We need the condition I mentioned, but I think the maps are clear: $A/A'\to B/B'$ should arise from $A\to B \to B/B'$ and so on.

Comment: @Slade: I think user26857's skepticism is whether the map $A' \to B'$ is induced by $A \to B$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in fact any short exact sequence $0\to X\stackrel{\alpha}{\to}Y\stackrel{\beta}{\to}Z\to0$, split or not, is isomorphic to the quotient of a split short exact sequence by a split short exact subsequence, as follows:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@.0@.0@.0\\
@.@VVV@VVV@VVV\\
0@>>>0@>>>X@>1>>X@>>>0\\
@.@VVV@VV\begin{pmatrix}1\\\alpha\end{pmatrix}V@VV\alpha V\\
0@>>>X@>\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}>>X\oplus Y@>\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix}>>Y@>>>0\\
@.@VV1V@VV\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&-1\end{pmatrix}V@VV-\beta V\\
0@>>>X@>\alpha>>Y@>\beta>>Z@>>>0\\
@.@VVV@VVV@VVV\\
@.0@.0@.0
\end{CD}$$

Comment: Good point. Is there a situation where the quotient sequence is split?